# ¿De qué forma puedo hacer una impresión para casos dinámicos dentro de una tabla?

Tags: php, html-tabla

Lo que necesito es imprimir una ficha de notas según ciclo, pero necesito que en la siguiente tabla me imprima un mensaje "BASICO" (así como el 2do echo del código, pero más dinámico) siempre y cuando la variable "$resultado['CICLO']" esté comprendida entre los valores 1-12, evidentemente quiero que este "BASICO" se imprima una sola vez en el inicio de la columna "IDIOMA" antes de imprimir cualquier ciclo y no en cada celda (debido a que el foreach hace una validación por cada celda), probé con if y break, pero me termina anulando la impresión de toda la tabla e imagino que hacerlo con if dentro de if será muy tedioso.

> Dejo constar que existen alumnos que tienen ciclo 5-20 y otros 1-20,
>   etc (no siempre tendrán los ciclos completos).
>   y mi intervalo de división de niveles por ciclo son BÁSICO: 1-12 / INTERMEDIO: 13-18 / AVANZADO: 19-24

```
  foreach ($resultados as $resultado)
  {
    echo '<tr>
            <td valign="top">'.$resultado[0].'</td>
            <td>';
    echo        ucfirst(strtolower($nombreidioma)).' '.numromanos($resultado[1]);
                  if ($resultado['CICLO']==13){
                        echo '</br></br><strong>'.$nombreidioma.' INTERMEDIO</strong>';
                      }
                  if ($resultado['CICLO']==18){
                        echo '</br></br><strong>'.$nombreidioma.' AVANZADO<strong>';
                      }
    echo  '</td>
            <td valign="top">';
                //var_dump($resultado['CICLO']);

             echo $resultado[2];
             if ($resultado['CICLO']==13){
                        echo '</br></br>';
                       }
            if ($resultado['CICLO']==18){
                        echo '</br></br>';
                       }
      echo '</td>
            <td valign="top">' .numaletras($resultado[2]). '</td>
            <td valign="top">' .$resultado[3]. '</td>
            <td valign="top">' .$resultado[4]. '</td>
          </tr>
        ';
  }
?>
```

Para mostrar una idea de los datos dejo una referencia:

CODIGO IDIOMA   NOTA    NOTA EN LETRAS  FECHA   OBSERVAC.

020003931   Ingles II   18  Dieciocho   13/03/08
020003931   Ingles III  16  Dieciseis   13/03/08
020003931   Ingles IV   16  Dieciseis   13/03/08
020003931   Ingles V    16  Dieciseis   13/04/08
020003931   Ingles VI   18  Dieciocho   13/03/08
020003931   Ingles VII  15  Quince  13/03/08
020003931   Ingles VIII 17  Decisiete   13/03/08
020003931   Ingles IX   15  Quince  13/03/08
020003931   Ingles XI   15  Quince  13/03/08
020003931   Ingles XII  15  Quince  13/03/08
020003931   Ingles XIII INGLES INTERMEDIO   15 Quince   13/03/08
020003931   Ingles XIV  16  Dieciseis   13/03/08
020003931   Ingles XV   16  Dieciseis   01/09/10
020003931   Ingles XVI  18  Dieciocho   05/10/10
020003931   Ingles XVII 18  Dieciocho   03/11/10
020003931   Ingles XVIII INGLES AVANZADO    17 Diecisiete   31/01/11
020003931   Ingles XIX  16  Dieciseis   03/03/11
020003931   Ingles XX   17  Diecisiete  04/04/11
020003931   Ingles XXI  15  Quince  09/05/11
020003931   Ingles XXII 16  Dieciseis   06/06/11
020003931   Ingles XXIII    17  Decisiete   08/08/11
020003931   Ingles XXIV 15  Quince  13/09/11

> Mis avances son:

```
switch($resultado['CICLO'])
{                    
  case 1:
    if ($resultado['CICLO']=1){
      echo 'es igual a 1.';  
    }
    break;

  case 2:
    if ($resultado[1]+1==$resultado[1+1])
    {
      echo 'es igual a 2';  
    }
    break;
  case 3:
    if ($resultado[1]=3){
      echo 'es igual a 3';  
    }
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

al no obtener alguna solución mas dinámica...
Logré solucionar mi problema con esto:

```
if ($resultados[0][1]==1 or
    $resultados[0][1]==2 or
    $resultados[0][1]==3 or
    $resultados[0][1]==4 or
    $resultados[0][1]==5 or
    $resultados[0][1]==6 or
    $resultados[0][1]==7 or
    $resultados[0][1]==8 or
    $resultados[0][1]==9 or
    $resultados[0][1]==10 or
    $resultados[0][1]==11 or
    $resultados[0][1]==12)
  {
    echo $nombreidioma.' BASICO</br>';
  }

  if($resultados[0][1]==13 or
     $resultados[0][1]==14 or
     $resultados[0][1]==15 or
     $resultados[0][1]==16 or
     $resultados[0][1]==17 or
     $resultados[0][1]==18)
  {
    echo $nombreidioma.' INTERMEDIO</br>';
    //break;
  }

  if($resultados[0][1]==19 or
     $resultados[0][1]==20 or
     $resultados[0][1]==21 or
     $resultados[0][1]==22 or
     $resultados[0][1]==23 or
     $resultados[0][1]==24 or
     $resultados[0][1]==25)
  {
    echo $nombreidioma.' AVANZADO</br>';
  }
```

Lo publico por si a alguien le sirve.